# how retrieve the value from checkbox buttons on Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I Am using Bootstrap's button plugin for my buttons, currently I have 6 Checkbox buttons and I need a Method to retrieve the value of every checked button to make some calculations. But I cannot figure how, I tried searching here And found a pretty good way but for Radio Buttons and for a single checkbox but didn't find any for multiple.

how can I make a Jquery method for sweeping the btnGroup elements and retrieve all the checked values in an array?

Please help!!

PS. I Am not native English speaker and I Am pretty new to Jquery, so sorry if its a noob question.

Example Html:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons id="btnGroup">
     <div class="col-auto">
        <label class="btn btn-outline-info">
        <input type="checkbox" name="btn1" id="" autocomplete="off" value="value1">value1</label>
    </div>
     <div class="col-auto">
        <label class="btn btn-outline-info">
        <input type="checkbox" name="btn2" id="" autocomplete="off" value="value2">value2</label>
    </div>
     <div class="col-auto">
        <label class="btn btn-outline-info">
        <input type="checkbox" name="btn3" id="" autocomplete="off" value="value3">value3</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I tried a method I found here but couldn't figure how to pass everything to an array and didn't understand the debug and valueGenre in the final part so I gave up https://jsfiddle.net/kmt26545/26/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this selector:

`$("#btnGroup input[type='checkbox']:checked")`

To get all the checked checkboxes in the div with the id `btnGroup`. You can then use `.each()` to loop over all the checked boxes and use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the value of each checked box.

Here I have logged out each value as an example.
See example below:

```js
let values = [];
$('.calculate').click(_ => {
  values = [];
  $("#btnGroup input[type='checkbox']:checked").each((_, {value}) => {
    values.push(value);
  });
  
  console.log(values);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-toolbar btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" id="btnGroup">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-info">
        <input type="checkbox" name="btn1" id="" autocomplete="off" value="value1">value1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-info">
        <input type="checkbox" name="btn2" id="" autocomplete="off" value="value2">value2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-info">
        <input type="checkbox" name="btn3" id="" autocomplete="off" value="value3">value3</label>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="calculate btn btn-primary btn-lg">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but didn't work for me, just got an "on" value in the console and don't know why... even if copy pasted your answer.

Comment: @luchitomario what do you expect to be outputted to the console?

Comment: i was expecting the values, What I need is  to save the values in an array or object so I can use those for further calculations.

Comment: Ok, so if you run my code snippet above, do your get the expected result?

Comment: yes!! I tried again and worked perfectly I made some changes trying solutions but now reversed and worked pretty good. Thanks a lot. Just one more thing, how can I save all the values to an array or a string or a object for further use? sorry, but just yesterday started with Jquery.

Comment: @luchitomario no worries, glad to help